# run "wget" command on running program

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card, ip-camera, smartcard-reader

I'm building program for parking system as my project.
The component/tools I used are : 
 - Raspberry Pi 2 with SD Card: Sandisk Ultra 8GB as the CPU, 
 - Barrier Gate 
 - NFC Card Reader as reader to the Smart Card
 - IP Camera, connected via ethernet

On my raspberry pi, i have script that will keep running to read the data from card reader ( if someone tapped) , and on the same time when someone tapped, I run the script "wget" like "wget --user=user --password=passowrd -O file.jpg

But, it is working only once at first attempt (download progress=100%) but later on second and next trial it never reach 100%, stuck at most at 50%.
I connected on the same network, I can ping the ip-address/url.

but each time I run 'wget' it cannot download the image from IP Camera.

Prev when I run the "wget" command on my laptop, it always success at awesome speed (0.06s) and download the captured image from ip camera.
anyone know what is the problem at?
 - wget command ? sd card ?
and sorry for the bad english

-G13

Answer (score 0):

You might try modifying your wget command. If you look in the man page for wget, there are `--tries` and `--read-timeout` options that you can use for when a download hangs.

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html